How to slice a time series pandas dataframe based on another dataframe of specific time series events logged in two rows?
First dataframe df1 timedelta index
Time                Power (kW)   
2020-12-31 06:10:00   490 
2020-12-31 00:10:10   493
2020-12-31 00:10:20   523
2020-12-31 00:10:30   476
2020-12-31 00:10:40   478
2020-12-31 00:10:50   491

...
...
...

Second dataframe df2 from the event logger
    Timestamp start         Timestamp end
0   2020-12-31 06:10:20 2021-01-31 06:10:40
13  2021-01-02 06:00:00 2021-01-02 06:20:20
181 2021-01-09 18:00:10 2021-01-10 18:50:50
195 2021-01-12 06:20:10 2021-01-12 06:20:30
255 2021-01-14 16:10:40 2021-01-14 16:30:50

Now I intend to extract the first dataframe timeseries for durations of the second two-column dataframe. All the time are in timedelta format.
Any help please
I tried with for loops
for i in df2['Timestamp start']:
    for j in df2['Timestamp end']:
       df3 = df1[i:j]
       print(df3)

But its, not slicing like that....
I am expecting something like this:
Suppose for the first row in df2
df3 = df1['2020-12-31 00:10:10' : '2020-12-31 00:10:40'

df3
> 2020-12-31 00:10:10   493
  2020-12-31 00:10:20   523
  2020-12-31 00:10:30   476
  2020-12-31 00:10:40   478

And for all the subsequent rows in a nice dataframe
